# Navbar Fixed top not working as seen in LayoutIt preview

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to create a navbar with fixed top in bootstrap.

I am tyring with Layoutit.com...

With the default layout in LayoutIt.com (with BS3), changed the navbar position to navbar fixed top. Checked the preview, it is working like a charm. Then I downloaded the content and executed locally. Boom, the navbar was fixed to top but the rest of the content is flowing behind the navbar.

Is there anything missing while download?

Comment: Please check you version of bootstrap.js and boostras.css

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chakrei/8e1npemc/).

If I'm clear with your question, I think that you are not using "padding top" for the second div so it is going under the navbar. In the above fiddle try removing "middle" class and check.

```
    .middle{
       padding-top: 100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add body top margin

```
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9295/

Also check you version of Jquery, bootstrap.js, and bootstrap.css